# importing for loop output to another for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I am facing problem while importing the output of a for-loop to another for loop.

`My python script`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a=list(np.sort(np.random.uniform(low=2, high=3, size=(3,))))
a = [ round(elem, 1) for elem in a ]
#print(a)

for i,b in enumerate(a):
    c=[b,b+1]
    print(c)

for lrng in np.linspace(0,3,3):
    d=[lrng, 15.0]
    print(d[0])
    e = {d[0]: c, d[1]:[2.0,2.0]}
    print(e)
```

Actually facing problem in this line of code `e = {d[0]: c, d[1]:[2.0,2.0]},` where value of `c` should be different but by this script i am getting repeated value.

```
current result

{0.0: [3.0, 4.0], 15.0: [2.0, 2.0]}
{1.5: [3.0, 4.0], 15.0: [2.0, 2.0]}
{3.0: [3.0, 4.0], 15.0: [2.0, 2.0]}


Expected result:

{0.0: [2.0, 3.0], 15.0: [2.0, 2.0]}
{1.5: [2.1, 3.1], 15.0: [2.0, 2.0]}
{3.0: [3.0, 4.0], 15.0: [2.0, 2.0]}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `c`'s value won't change in the second loop because it's already calculated and your second `for` loop is using the calculated value of `c` for calculating `e`.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Thanks for your suggestions. Can you please suggest little more how should i rewrite the code so that output will be same as expected result

Comment: you keep over writing `c` in your 2nd loop you need to create an empty `ilst` and then append values to it.

Comment: It seems like you would want to have `c` returned from a `function` call or even better from a `generator`. If you're not familiar with those concepts, then simply compute `c` at every iteration in your second loop (and discard the first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep over writting the value if `c` which is why you only ever get the last value calculated in the next loop. You need to store the values in a list then read them back as needed.

Here I've created an empty list `c = []` & then in the 3rd loop read out the values of `c` as indexed by the counter `idx`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a=list(np.sort(np.random.uniform(low=2, high=3, size=(3,))))
a = [ round(elem, 1) for elem in a ]
#print(a)

c = []
for i,b in enumerate(a):
    c.append([b,b+1])
    print(b, b+1)

for idx, lrng in enumerate(np.linspace(0,3,3)):
    d=[lrng, 15.0]
    print(d[0])
    e = {d[0]: c[idx], d[1]:[2.0,2.0]}
    print(e)
```